# How to make a alarm

Tags: android-studio, datetime, alarm

I want to know how to make a simple alarm that rings and makes you input a date and time.

I have searched on google and there are no example available and even if there is, its too complicated

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.my.package.MY_UNIQUE_ACTION");
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, 
                                      intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your intent is fine, to schedule something in the future, use the `AlarmManager`. Try this

```
    final AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (alarms != null) {
        alarms.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmDate.getTime(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }
```